# How fix http request in php?

Tags: php, curl

I input this code

```php
<?php
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

include 'config/api.php';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/players/%238CCURC2G');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer $CRapi';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);


$profile = http_request("https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/players/%238CCURC2G");

// ubah string JSON menjadi array
$profile = json_decode($profile, TRUE);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($profile);
echo "</pre>";
```

and showing error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function http_request() in C:\xampp\htdocs\fanca\supercell\test.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fanca\supercell\test.php on line 25

Comment: You don't have `http_request` defined, so what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this function:
http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.http-request.php

You need to install pecl_http module first:
http://docs.php.net/manual/da/http.install.php

However this module currently has unavailable DLLs for Win and I believe you do not need it, as you are performing request by curl to the very same URL. So just comment/delete what is below `curl_close ($ch);` and you should get your script working